# Export large amount of data (20000 rows) from Mysql to excel (with Php)

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import

I want to **export** large amount of data (20000 rows) from Mysql to excel (with PHP)
data comes from two tables.
Each record of first table have the ID of second table record.
I am using **PHPExcel** Library.

Pseudocode:

```
$first_table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_1")

foreach($first_table as $row){

   $store_id = $row['store_id'];

   $second_table =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_2 Where ID = $store_id");

}
```

In this case mysql query runs number of time (record found in first table)
now problem is that it takes too long time for processing and at the end no result php screen becomes blank(white)......  I think this is execution timeout problem...

Any solution ??

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Check out [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) if time is not a concern. Also, it might be browser problem.

Comment: Add some log informations to know if there is a probleme : ìf ($i % 1000 = 0) echo "line %i";\'. And I suggest to execute your code in the CLI.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use PHPExcel? Maybe you can just export it to separate csv files and then use them?

Comment: @peterm's answer will vastly improve the speed... a single database query to retrieve all the data will be a lot faster than 20001 retrieval queries against the database to retrieve the data row by row

Answer (score 2):

IMHO 20k rows isn't so big. How about utilizing `JOIN` and get a complete resultset in one roundtrip to MySql

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.store_id = t2.store_id
```

*Optimize select portion of the query so that you return only columns that you really need.*

It's not clear from your question, but If you need just to export data that can be later opened in Excel and not to build a fancy report then you can use `INTO OUTFILE` clause to generate CSV file very fast

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/tablename.csv'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.store_id = t2.store_id
```